# `Minimize` with conditions on `Integers` does not find a correct answer

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I want to find the minimum m which satisfies conditions as below:

```
Minimize[{m, m > 0 && Mod[m 3.1, 0.5] == 0}, m, Integers]
(* {1., {m -> 1}} *)
```

Obviously, the answer is m=5, however, Mathematica11.1 does not find the answer.
How can I instruct MM to find the correct answer?

Comment: Mathematica v12.2. gives an error message `NMinimize::nosat: Obtained solution does not satisfy the following constraints within Tolerance -> 0.001`: {-Mod[3.1 m,0.5]==0}.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Minimize[{m, m > 0 && 31/10 m == 1/2 k && k ∈ Integers}, {m, k}, Integers]
```

> `{5, {m -> 5, k -> 31}}`

Thanks @BobHanlon

```
Minimize[{m, m > 0 && 3.1 m == .5 k // Rationalize} , {m,    k}, Integers]
```

Comment: +1 Note that `k \[Element] Integers` is redundant

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks! I forgot that the last ` Integers` restrict `{m,k}` to `Integers`

Comment: I understand the solution. Why does the `Mod` or the `Minimize` not work for decimal representations?